# how write sql query with multiple join?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have fours tables and I wanted to join all three tables with the one table.

I have listed my problem as follows:

Tables:

1. `users`
2. `user_training`
3. `user_courses`
4. `user_certificates`

I wanted to get the data from `[2,3,4]` tables that `user_id` field matches with the `users` table `ID` field.

When I try the `INNER JOIN` it gives me the result for users that are common in all the tables, But I just wanted to check the `[2,3,4]` tables with the table [1] Records.

My Query...

```
SELECT  A.training_name AS 'training_name', C.course_name AS 'course_name',   D.certificate_name AS 'certificate_name'
FROM user_training AS A INNER JOIN users AS B ON A.user_id=B.ID INNER JOIN user_courses AS C ON B.ID = C.user_id INNER JOIN user_certificates AS D ON B.ID = D.user_id;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN`. Users with no entries in `_training`, `_courses` or `_certificates` will just have `NULL` values in those fields then.

Comment: show us the query you have written

Answer (score 0):

use `left join`

```
    select u.* from users u 
    left join user_training ut on ut.user_id=u.user_id 
    left join user_courses uc on uc.user_id=u.user_id 
    left join user_certificates uct on uct.user_id=u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

With this one you are getting all users and their respective trainings:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_training` ON `users`.`id` = `user_training`.`user_id`
```

Changing `*_trainig` to `*_courses` or `*_certificates` will return all users with respected courses or certificates.

If you need to get data in one query, try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_training` ON `users`.`id` = `user_training`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `user_courses` ON `users`.`id` = `user_courses`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `user_certificates` ON `users`.`id` = `user_certificates`.`user_id`
```

If user has no trainings, courses, certificates all remaining fields will be `null`-ed.